# Enumerable.Count not working

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, enumerable

I am monitoring the power of a laser and I want to know when n consecutive measurements are outside a safe range. I have a `Queue(Of Double)` which has n items (2 in my example) at the time it's being checked. I want to check that *all* items in the queue satisfy a condition, so I pass the items through a `Count()` with a predicate. However, the count function always returns the number of items in the queue, even if they don't all satisfy the predicate.

```
ElseIf _consecutiveMeasurements.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(m) m <= Me.CriticalLowLevel) = ConsecutiveCount Then
    _ownedISetInstrument.Disable()
    ' do other things
```

A view of the debugger with the execution moving into the `If`.

[image]

Clearly, there are two measurements in the queue, and they are both greater than the `CriticalLowLevel`, so the count should be zero. I first tried `Enumerable.Where(predicate).Count()` and I got the same result. What's going on?

**Edit:**

Of course the values are below the CriticalLowLevel, which I had mistakenly set to 598 instead of 498 for testing. I had over-complicated the problem by focusing my attention on the code when it was my test case which was faulty. I guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees, so they say. Thanks Eric for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake in your text - shouldn't the third to last line say `and they are both less than the CriticalLowLevel` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your debug snapshot, it looks like both of your measurements are less than the critical level of 598.0, so I would expect the count to match the queue length.

Both data points are <= Me.CriticalLowLevel.

Can you share an example where one of the data points is > Me.CriticalLowLevel that still exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Well I guess I was missing something simple... Doh!

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)